# print statements not executed when attached to a process in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

I have successfully attached to a process by PID number in xCode. What is frustrating is that I see no print() statements being executed while operating with the running app. Is that normal? Should I check a check box somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is normal. A process inherits its standard input, output, and error output when it is created. After that point, the process can change its own standard file descriptors, but they can't be changed from the outside.

So, a program which was launched by some other means than being launched by Xcode will not have its output directed to Xcode's console window. Where, exactly, its output is directed depends on how it was launched. If it was launched from the GUI (e.g. Finder, Dock, other GUI app), then its normal output is probably discarded (directed to /dev/null) and its error output will go to the console log (viewable using /Applications/Utilities/Console.app). If it was run directly from a shell in Terminal, then its output would go that Terminal window.

Comment: Can I get around this problem? I really need to see print statements for debugging purposes.

Comment: Launch your program from Xcode or possibly from a Terminal window. Or switch from `print()` to `NSLog()` and look for your output in the console log. Other than that, no.

Comment: Hi. Beating a dead horse here but I have a related question. I get my print-outs in the SIM but not while using device (watch). I changed to nslog but no difference. Is this normal?